# What is the best way to create various IndexedDB objectStores within the same script?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

For my IndexedDB I'm pulling various Ajax requests that will provide the data to the objectStores.
Since transactions are asynchronous how should I chain the creation of the objectStores?
I'm thinking in doing it like this:

1- Pull all the Ajax requests in the beginning of the script.

2- Request to open the DB.

3- In the onsuccess handler open the first transaction to create the first objectStore and insert the respective data.

4- Call the oncomplete event on the first transaction to create a second transaction.

5- Do this for all the objectStores that need to be created.

Is this the best way, or should I just write all the transactions inside the onsuccess handler of the indexedDB.open request?

Can I create various objectStores and insert large amounts of data at the same time without causing errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything in one transaction. If you open your transaction, you define the scope of this transaction. The scope can exist out of multiple object stores. By providing an array of all the names of the object stores you want to target.

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["obj1", "obj2"]);
```

Comment: And there's no problem inserting lots of data into multiple objecStores at the same time?

Comment: Not that I know. The only disadvantage is when something goes wrong inside the transaction, It won't be committed.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try it and see how it goes.
Thanks Kristof.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience transactions tend to close when waiting for an AJAX response so you have to open the transaction in the success handler for the AJAX response.

There is definitely nothing wrong with having multiple, overlapping transactions "running" in parallel, but in practice JavaScript is still single-threaded - you'll find that even the AJAX success handlers run sequentially and ordering is fairly predictable (though not guaranteed), so if you open a transaction in each, and then process the data with a series of puts, what you may actually see is:

```
openAjax1()
openAjax2()
ajax1Complete()
  // in here, open transaction1 and call objectStore1.put() many times
ajax2Complete()
  // in here, open transaction2 and call objectStore2.put() many times
put()  // from ajax1
put()  // from ajax1
put()  // from ajax1
...    // from ajax1
       // transaction1 completes
put()  // from ajax2
put()  // from ajax2
put()  // from ajax2
...    // from ajax2
       // transaction2 completes
```

In theory, the only way to actually make things happen in parallel is to use worker threads, but even then most implementations will funnel the work down to a single thread. In practice, the backends are pretty good about optimizing "bulk" writes together so you wouldn't even get much of a performance improvement from using workers.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing (inside the onsuccess function of the IndexedDb.open function, and of course after creating objectStores and indexes):  var xhr_1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr_1.open("GET", "http://localhost/webservice1.asp", true); 
xhr_1.addEventListener("load", function () {
if (xhr_1.status === 200) { "the objectStore transaction and put function"}, fallowed by the next Ajax requests.
I have have tested it and I've managed (running locally) to get and put five tables with a total of 282.039 records in 1 minute 10 seconds, what I think is quit satisfying. Thanks alecf.

Comment: This way I'm only opening transactions on "status === 200", so as the data falls I open the transaction and put the results. The only problem I had was I was calling a db.close(); inside every transaction's oncomplete, so as the first request was received and "putted" the the others would encounter a closed db and throw an error, something like "trying to open or change a db that does not allow mutations", so I had to take it out. I thought it was good procedure to close the transaction at the end of each operation. Is there a way to close a particular transaction or it doesn't matter anyway?

Comment: db.close() closes the ENTIRE database, not just the transaction. The transaction will auto-commit, you don't have to do it explicitly.